# Why do I get 401 UNAUTHORIZED when I'm entering to WSS 3.0 site?

Tags: wss-3.0, 2007, anonymous-authentication

When I'm opening for the first time my webpage on WSS 3.0 I always get 401 UNAUTHORIZED. I was trying a lot of resolutions from Google results. I disabled loop back check. Added administrator rights for sharepoint account. I have to add that I'm using anonymous access to default site.
Can anybody help me to resolve this issue? Please.

Comment: loopback check would give you a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can experience this behaviour if in your web application web.config file the compilation batch setting is set to true. If this is the case, please set it to false and see if this resolves the problem.

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="false" />
```

The issue is described in more detail by [this blog post](http://vspug.com/radi/2008/08/06/sharepoint-401-unauthorized-search-and-forms-authentication/).
Also notice that the [Microsoft Knowledge Base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953459) seems to indicate that setting the batch attribute to true is *not supported*.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled anonymous access in IIS?

Comment: Yes it's enabled. I've check it.